# Rails: How do I upgrade Node js in my docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

So I have a rails app that uses docker. It has A Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file. I'm trying to upgrade the node version from 12.x to 16.x . I changed the nodesource set up the dockerfile was using from 12.x to 16.x (`RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -`). I then ran my docker compose up to run all my containers and opened a shell in one of the containers to check what version of node it was using. It's still using a node version 12.22.12. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild your image(s) with

```
docker-compose up --build
```

or just specific service

```
docker-compose up --build rails
```

Of course you can add other options as well, for example

```
docker-compose up --build -d rails
```